# Extract App Intents Metadata - very slow build step

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodebuild, ios16, appintents

The app intents extraction from the new `AppIntents` framework takes a lot of time, even when changes in code don't touch the intents directly.

In the build log reasons for this step to happen differ, but mostly it's that "file X changed" and I wonder if I can somehow cache that intent or at least extract this metadata only in Production builds? Simple `#if debug` doesn't prevent this step from being executed.

[image: Timeline for build]

Answer (score 1):

So far the only idea I came with is to switch the executable run by xcode.

It's inside `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` named `appintentsmetadataprocessor` **make sure to backup it!**. I replaced it with simple

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

Of course you need to add `chmod +x` to it.

Then your widgets won't work, but if you're building releases through CI you should be safe + you can always put the previous `appintentsmetadataprocessor` back.

Now the step takes 0.1 sec.